# Is there a way to process scrapy.Request object in the shell?

Tags: python, scrapy

In the terminal, I ran

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

I created the following spider in the `spiders` folder

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
```

In the terminal, I ran

```
scrapy shell 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
```

This all works fine as in the Python shell that opens up I get

```
>>> response
<200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
```

Now, I ran

```
>>> next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
>>> next_page
'/page/2/'

>>> response.follow(next_page)
<GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>

>>> type(response.follow(next_page))
<class 'scrapy.http.request.Request'>
```

I would like to get a new `Response` object in the shell, based on the link to `next_page`. Is this possible at all? Any help very much appreciated.

I tried the below already, but couldn't fix the error.

```
>>> scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware.process_request(response.follow(next_page), "quotes")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: process_request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'spider'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fetch()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#available-shortcuts):

```
>>> fetch(response.follow(next_page))
```